# Why I am getting errors with messages when using expo-av

Tags: react-native, expo

I have been having this issue for a few weeks now and was unable to pinpoint the issue. I am getting an error with no message when using the `setAudioModeAsync` from expo-ac:

I have the following component:

```js
export default (base64: string) => {
  const [sound, setSound] = useState<Audio.Sound>()
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState<boolean>(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    Audio.requestPermissionsAsync()
    Audio.setAudioModeAsync({ allowsRecordingIOS: true })
  }, [])

  ...
}
```

But the line `Audio.setAudioModeAsync({ allowsRecordingIOS: true })` creates errors like this one:

```
WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error
Error
    at construct (native)
    at apply (native)
    at _construct (http://192.168.0.199:8081/src/index.tsx.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:4480:28)
    at Wrapper (http://192.168.0.199:8081/src/index.tsx.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:4442:25)
    at construct (native)
    at _createSuperInternal (http://192.168.0.199:8081/src/index.tsx.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:124210:322)
    at call (native)
    at CodedError (http://192.168.0.199:8081/src/index.tsx.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:124223:26)
```

Removing this line gets rid of the issue. Why am I getting these errors and how can I get rid of them?

I am using expo-av version `~13.4.1` with expo version `~49.0.11`.

Answer (score 1):

The error was cause due to the fact that the operation in the useEffect should have been asynchronous as opposed to synchronous. To fix this, I simply did:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    Audio.requestPermissionsAsync().then(() =>
      Audio.setAudioModeAsync({ allowsRecordingIOS: true, playsInSilentModeIOS: true }),
    )
  }, [])
```

But I am sure there are more elegant ways to do this.